# Parar uma function já iniciada em JQuery

Tags: jquery, funções, break

O problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho uma função chamada **showJsonProducts();**
quero que, quando eu chamar outra function ela pare de ser executada,
exemplo:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
 showJsonProducts.stop(); 
ou 
 showJsonProducts().break();
```

existe algo assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez carregada na memória, não tem como impedir que a função seja chamada (pelo menos não conheço um método).

Mas você pode criar uma variável global que ignore o conteúdo (ou parte dele) da função. Defina a variável como `false` e inclua o conteúdo da função dentro de um `if` verificando o *status* da variável. Quando você chamar a outra função, altere o *status* da variável para `true`:

```js
var ativa = false;
function teste(){
   if(!ativa){
      // ... todo o conteúdo da função aqui
      alert("Olá!");
   }
}

function desativa(){
   ativa = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Chamar função" onclick="teste()" />
<input type="button" value="desativar função" onclick="desativa()" />
```

Desta forma a função ainda será chamada, mas não terá nenhum efeito porque não entrará no `if` dentro dela. No seu caso:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    ativa = true;
});
```

#### Edit

Uma outra forma é redefinir a função:

```
window.teste = function(){
   return false;
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
function teste(){
   alert("Olá!");
}

function desativa(){
   window.teste = function(){
      return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Chamar função" onclick="teste()" />
<input type="button" value="desativar função" onclick="desativa()" />
```